# [iPhone]changing the color of the info dark button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

please i would like to change the color of the info Dark button shown in the picture(top right) to be visible.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 ways:

- using Interface Builder: select the button, change it's type to "Info Light"
- programmatically: yourButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];

Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Use below piece of code you reference,

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
UIBarButtonItem *customItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = customItem;
[customItem release];
```